# JSON.aprse() error when using php json_encode()

Tags: javascript, php, json

- i know that this question asked before but i have never found anything working for my case
- i have 2 array which is looking like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [`19 January 2021`] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 36
                            [1] => 817
                            [2] => 67
                        )

                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [`20 January 2021`] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 79
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

- then i used `json_encode()` php method to encode this array which will be looking like this

```
[{"`19 January 2021`":[["36","817","67"]]}][{"`20 January 2021`":[["79"]]}]
```

- but when i'm tring to use in js `JSON.parse()` it's give me this error
  [image]
- can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individually, these two are totally fine JSON strings.

```
[{"`19 January 2021`":[["36","817","67"]]}]
[{"`20 January 2021`":[["79"]]}]
```

You can't parse them both together at the same time just by concatenating them though. Either parse them individually:

```
JSON.parse(arr1String);
JSON.parse(arr2String);
```

Or combine them into a single JSON object.

```
echo json_encode([
    "arr1" => $arr1,
    "arr2" => $arr2
]);
```

Comment: -it's looking like JSON.parse() parseing them one by one but i can't do that because it's looking like they both indexed at the zero position which mean if you write $arr[0][0] - that's will give you the zero index value of both array's

Comment: i'm tring to access the data inside table this table conatins names of another tables in another database so i should to take them then find them in the other database but this tables every one has a multiple rows so what i's tring is to get the names of this tables and eveyone contains it's rows values in json syntax to use it in js in a page

Comment: ok i get eveyone inside index and it's working now thanks